# Adding each int in a line from a file to a list in C

Tags: c

Im trying to add each integer in a line to a list.

```
char* token;
while(1){
     if (fgets(line,MAX_LEN, in)==NULL) break;
     token = strtok(line, " ");
     List L = newList();
     while(token != NULL){
            append(L, atoi(token));
     }
}
```

Reading from my In file is working perfectly and newList() and append() are methods I have already written that work.

My question is why does this program get killed when I run it? and also what changes do I have to make to fix it?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. Could you post the code that opens your file handle, and post the error you get when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `token` does not change after the line

```
token = strtok(line, " ");
```

So the loop runs until the system objects to appending another item. You should continue to call `strtok` in the loop, like this

```
while(token != NULL){
    append(L, atoi(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Note that `List L` won't be accessible once the outer loop has finished so that should be moved outside. I suggest this more idiomatic solution:

```
List L = newList();
while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL) {
    char *token = strtok(line, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        append(L, atoi(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```